# Match and Store Python Dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out a way to match a given value in a dataframe column to another dataframe column, and then storing an AGE from df1 in df2.

e.g. Matching VAL in df1 to VAL in df2. If the two are equal, store AGE from df1 in AGE df2.

```
| df1 | VAL | AGE |
|:--- |:---:|----:|
|  0  | 20  | 25  |
|  1  | 10  | 29  |
|  2  | 50  | 21  |
|  4  | 20  | 32  |
|  5  | 00  | 19  |


| df2 | VAL | AGE |
|:--- |:---:|----:|
|  0  | 00  | []  |
|  1  | 10  | []  |
|  2  | 20  | []  |
|  4  | 30  | []  |
|  5  | 40  | []  |
|  6  | 50  | []  |
```

edit: AGE in df2 stores an array of values rather than a single value

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x = df1.groupby("VAL").agg(list)
df2["AGE"] = df2["VAL"].map(x["AGE"]).fillna({i: [] for i in df2.index})

print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
   VAL       AGE
0    0      [19]
1   10      [29]
2   20  [25, 32]
4   30        []
5   40        []
6   50      [21]
```